# Vectorizing order in R

Tags: r

I am trying to order each row in a matrix with few columns and many rows. Is there a vectorized version of this in R? More concretely, let's set our seed to 10 and make an example matrix:

```
set.seed(10)
example.matrix = replicate(12,runif(500000))
```

To order example.matrix, I would,

```
ordered.example = apply(example.matrix,1,order)
```

But that is very slow and I would love something faster. 
As an analogy,

```
rowSums(example.matrix)
```

Is preferable to,

```
apply(example.matrix,1,sum)
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: takes 8 seconds for me, I wouldn't say it is very slow :)

Comment: Right. That was a toy example of smaller size than what I have, and I need to do this many times.

Comment: I understand that, but the point remains. There are several other options to optimize for speed, e.g. writing the code in C++, using parallel computing.They may give better effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way of speeding it up 10x. It's specifically tailored to your example and depending on what your real data is like this method may or may not work.

The idea is to add 0 to first row, 1 to second and so on, then collapse it to a vector, sort that and then recombine into a matrix:

```
N = 12; M = 500000; d = replicate(N,runif(M))

system.time(d1<-t(apply(d, 1, order)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  11.26    0.06   11.34 

system.time(d2<-matrix(order(as.vector(t(matrix(as.vector(d) + 0:(M-1), nrow = M)))) -
                       rep(0:(M-1), each = N)*N, nrow = M, byrow = T))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.39    0.14    1.53 

# Note: for some reason identical() fails, but the two are in fact the same
sum(abs(d1-d2))
# 0
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit faster (the key bit being `order(row(em), em)`):

```
set.seed(10)
em <- replicate(12,runif(500000))
system.time(a <- matrix(em[order(row(em), em)], nrow=nrow(em), byrow=TRUE))
#    user  system elapsed 
# 5.36    0.12    5.80 

set.seed(10)
example.matrix <- replicate(12,runif(500000))
system.time(ordered.example <- apply(example.matrix,1,order))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   13.36    0.09   15.52 

identical(a, ordered.example)
# [1] FALSE
```